# ASP.NET MVC collection comes empty in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**SOLVED**
I had to fill the collection in the controller and then use the approach explained in the comment bellow. Thank you all for help :)

I have a simple site, where I want to add prices of the specific food to all the shops.
I select the Item, like Apples and then lists all the shops where I can add the price.

the model has a collection ( List ). In the view I go through the shops, create new instance of the Price, have text box where I enter the price and add it to the collection.

Problem is, that the collection comes empty in the controller.

Any suggestions ? Thanks !

Edit: Shop collection is there just to provide ShopID. Prices collection is the one, which comes to the view empty and i need to fill it, to work with the data in the controller.

Model:

```
public class PriceMultiple
{
    private List<Price> _NewPrices;
    public List<Price> NewPrices 
    { 
        get
        {
            if (_NewPrices == null)
                _NewPrices = new List<Price>();
            return _NewPrices;
        }
        set { _NewPrices = value; }
    }
...
}
```

View:

```html
...
@foreach (Shop shop in ViewBag.ShopsToLoad)
{
    Price price = new Price();
    price.ItemID = Model.ItemID.Value;
    price.ShopID = shop.ShopID;

    @shop.Name

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("price.Value", "Cena")
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("price.Value")
        </div>
    </div>
    Model.NewPrices.Add(price);
}
...
```

Comment: Could you post the part of your controller where you actually set the value of the NewPrices list as everything else seems to be in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue stems from the fact that your rendered markup does not conform to the ASP.Net Wire Format for model binding:

ref: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

In short, you need to ensure that when you deal with collections, the form controls are given very specific names. From the ref:

> The way that we read in the properties is by looking for parameterName[index].PropertyName.  The index must be zero-based and unbroken.

You haven't provided your model that your View is typed to, so I'm going to guess here, but your controls need to be rendered out something like:

```
<input type="text" name="shop[0].price[0]" />
<input type="text" name="shop[0].price[1]" />
<input type="text" name="shop[1].price[0]" />
<input type="text" name="shop[1].price[1]" />
```

The stock helpers in Razor won't build these out for you, you're going to have to build a custom editor, or simply write the inputs out - remember, MVC doesn't get in your way!

```
@for(var i = 0; i < ViewBag.ShopsToLoad.length; i++){
    @for(var j = 0; j < ViewBag.ShopsToLoad[i].Prices.length; j++){
       <input type="text" name="shop[@i].price[@j]" />
    }
}
```

Comment: The prices collection belongs to the model. Shop collection is there only to provide ShopID and number of repetitions, thats it.
What i need to do, is to add items into the collection of prices, which belongs to the Model (PriceMultiple)

Comment: OK, solved, I had to fill the the collection in the controller. Thank you for this i would have this problem probably anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

From past experiences posting collections to a controller using basic forms caused me trouble.

I suggest that you use a Javascript MVVC framework to collect the values and then post to your controller.

I've used knockout and angular to do this. Knockout is a bit simpler to start out if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make your life a little easier if you did more work in the controller and model and gave the view a strongly-typed model to deal with.

The following is just off the top of my head so don't just cut-and-paste it and expect it to work.

Model

```
public class PriceByShop
{
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public string ShopName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Prices()
{
    var pricesByShop = new List<PriceByShop>();

    // some code here to add an object to the list for each shop
    // initialize Price with existing price or set to 0...

    return View( pricesByShop );
}
```

View

```
@model List<PriceByShop>

@for( int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++ )
{
    @Model[i].ShopName

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor( model => model[i].Price, "Cena" )
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor( model => model[i].Price )
        </div>
    </div>
}
```